# How to translate CMake command into bash\cmd and pass it as argument in other cmake command?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform

I want to embed GSL as external project.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        gsl
        GIT_REPOSITORY git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gsl.git
        DOWNLOAD_DIR external/gsl
        SOURCE_DIR external/gsl
        PATCH_COMMAND file(COPY external/gsl/contrib/CMakeLists.txt external/gsl/contrib/ ) 
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        BINARY_DIR ./
        INSTALL_DIR ./
    )
```

Yet `file(COPY external/gsl/contrib/CMakeLists.txt external/gsl/contrib/ )` is CMake command (that could generally work on any platform). I wonder how to translate it into `cmd` to be able to call it in `PATCH_COMMAND` in crossplatform manner without creating platform dependent logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake implements a predefined set of portable commands available through invocation

```
cmake -E <command> <args>
```

For example, `file(COPY)` cmake command has command-line equivalent

```
cmake -E COPY <file> <destination>
```

For more information, see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html) about `cmake` command line tool.

If there is no command-line equvalent for some cmake command(s), one may store required sequence of the commands in file, and perform these commands with

```
cmake -P <script>
```